# Image to the created file

Tags: c#, image, winforms, file

Can we set image or bitmap to the created or existing text, xml or word files?

If so, please let me know how to set bitmap or images to the files.

I want to change the default bitmap of the files.

[image]

Regards,
Amal

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to change the file icons?

Comment: yes. i would like to change the default file icons.

Comment: If you want different icons for created or existing files then you could write a shell extension icon handler : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon of a particular file extension, use the following code which enters all the needed information in the registry:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

// Associate file extension with progID, description, icon and application
public static void Associate(string extension, string progID, string description, string icon, string application)
{
   Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension).SetValue("", progID);
   if (progID!=null && progID.Length>0)
      using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(progID))
      {
         if (description!=null)
            key.SetValue("", description);
         if (icon!=null)
            key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", ToShortPathName(icon));
         if (application!=null)
            key.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\Open\Command").SetValue("", ToShortPathName(application) + " \"%1\"");
      }
}

// Return true if extension already associated in registry
public static bool IsAssociated(string extension)
{
   return (Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension, false)!=null);
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetShortPathName(string lpszLongPath, [Out] StringBuilder lpszShortPath, uint cchBuffer);

// Return short path format of a file name
private static string ToShortPathName(string longName)
{
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(1000);
   uint iSize = (uint) s.Capacity;
   uint iRet = GetShortPathName(longName, s, iSize);
   return s.ToString();
}
```

And call it this way:

```
if (!IsAssociated(".ext"))
   Associate(".ext", "ClassID.ProgID", "ext File", "YourIcon.ico", "YourApplication.exe");
```

(from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/621/Associate-File-Extension-with-Shell-OPEN-command-a?msg=1589623#xx1589623xx)

Additionally if you can also change the icon of any given folder. This is not what you asked for, but if you want to find out more I suggest you look at this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9331/Create-Icons-for-Folders-in-Windows-Explorer-Using

Comment: i could not get idea on passing parameters for Associate().

Comment: What do you mean? string extension => file extension for the file type you want to change the icon of ie. '.txt' or '.doc', string progID => keep it as "ClassId.ProgId", string description => whatever you want - it is the description of your file type, string icon => the path of your icon, string application => path of your application

Comment: you have mentioned extension as file type. but registry is opened using the provided extension in Associate() method which could not be done

Comment: registry can't be opened, since no registry in extension